# A/B testing conversion paths (using django or out of the box services)

Tags: django, ab-testing

I want to have an A/B test as follows:

Control: Test percentage of users that fill out a form on the main page and click submit.
Test 1: (Form removed) Test percentage of users who click just a button on the main page and then continue to fill out the form in the following page and hit submit.

I've looked at [django-ab](https://github.com/johnboxall/django-ab) and [django-lean](https://bitbucket.org/akoha/django-lean/wiki/Home) but I'm not sure whether I can do this type of test with either.